# Can't insert into my table because of Date Conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textBox with an ajax calendar extender, and a button. When I click on the button it must fire a code that inserts a new record into the table "Material". this is my textBox Code

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateDG" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="162px" 
  ontextchanged="txtDateDG_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" 
  CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDateDG_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
   Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDateDG">
   </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

and here is my button code

```
 con.charger("insert into Materiel values ('" + txtServiceTag.Text + "', '" + txtPeriodeL.Text + "', '" + txtPeriodeG.Text + "','"
        + cmbMarque.SelectedIndex + "','" + cmbDesignation.SelectedIndex + "','" + (cmbSerie.SelectedIndex + 1) + "', NULL, NULL, '" +
        cmbEntite.SelectedIndex + "','" + txtDateD.Text + "','" + txtDateF.Text + "')", false);
        con.charger("insert into Stocker Values (2, '" + txtServiceTag.Text + "'", false);
```

" con.charger " : I am using a class where the sqlCommande/sqlConnection/DataSet is executing. I'm doing like so, just to avoid typing all the code each time.
It's giving me this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
I tried this method but I was still displaying the error

```
DateTime dD = convert.toDateTime(txtDateD.Text);
```

and this

```
dateTime dD = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

The txtDateD's type in my table is Date, and not DateTime

Comment: What is `con.charger`? Are you using some sort of ORM here?

Comment: I edited the question, please read it.

Comment: Please read about SQL injection.

Comment: Along with the above, you're not telling us what string value you're passing in that's failing to convert.

Comment: I said that I am using a calendar extender on the txtDateD textBox, so I'm selecting a date from the calendar

Comment: Show us the string that is getting passed from the calendar control.

Comment: This is my query : insert into Materiel values ('123E', '12', '12','1','3','1', NULL, NULL, '6','21/07/2014','21/07/2015') the two NULL values are okay ! they must be null.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using SQL parameters which will

1. Fix your date conversion issue
2. Protect you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Using SQL parameters will allow you to pass your date as `DateTime` rather than a formatted `string`, it's best to let the framework decide which format is required for storage.

Here's an example of how you would do that using `SqlCommand` / `SqlConnection`

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString")) 
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
{ 
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Materiel VALUES (@textParam, @intParam, @dateParam, ...)";  
    // add parameters
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textParam", "blah blah");  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intParam", 12345);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateParam", DateTime.UtcNow);  
    ...

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
    catch(SqlException e)
    {
        // do something with exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how

Comment: I tried that, but it's giving me an error `cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Materiel values(@ST,@PL, @PG, @IDM, @IDT, @IDS, @IDEm, @REP, @IDEN, @DD, @DD)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST", txtServiceTag.Text);` The @ST is the serviceTag and it's type is Varchar(20) in my table, when I click on the button it's giving me this error Incorrect syntax near '123F'